# Kotlin: гонка потоков

Tags: kotlin

```
        var i = 0
        MainScope().launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            (1..1000).map {
                launch {
                    (1..1000).forEach {
                        i++

                    }
                }
            }.joinAll()
            logInfo("${i++}")
        }
```

Этот код не всегда будет выводить в результат правильное число.
Нашел 3 способа решения на сайте Котлина:

1. использовать `Atomic`
   *(а что, если наша переменная не примитив Атомик, а наш класс?)*
2. указать как диспатчер `newSingleThreadContext`. тогда все выполнится на 1-ом потоке и проблем не будет
   *(пф... мы за асинхронность или где?)*
3. использовать `Mutext`
   *(работет, но сиииильно снижает скорость выполнения кода)*

подскажите: как правильно поступать в такой ситуации?

p.s. рабочий, но медленный код с Mutex (может тут, что можно поправить?)

```
        var i = 0
        val mutex = Mutex()
        MainScope().launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            (1..1000).map {
                launch {
                    (1..1000).forEach {
                        mutex.withLock {
                            i++
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.joinAll()
            logInfo("${i++}")
        }
```

Comment: Чудес не бывает, mutex фактически симулирует исполнение в одном треде, поэтому так медленно. Реальная асинхронность будет видна только в случае длинных вычислений и коротких записей результата. У вас же 100% времени это запись результата, вот и получается неэффективно. Это как хоть 100 грузчиков нанять, если дверь в склад на одного, быстро разгрузить не выйдет.

Comment: Из аналогии с грузчиками вылазит еще одна подсказка - делайте больше дверей :) Распараллеливайте результат.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja но ведь даже через newSingleThreadContext получается быстрее (( а есть еще решения, кроме этих 3 (2 их которых сомнительные)?

Comment: mutex просто очень тяжелая штука, в один тред без блокировок ваш тест быстрее и получается.

Comment: Вот возможно вам подойдет. В Котлине реального опыта нет, в Go отлично применяется для мультипоточного взаимодействия. Хоть миллион потоков пишет, один читает и никаких блокировок. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html

Comment: А просто `synchronized` блок для `i++` использовать? Не быстрее `Mutex` будет?

Comment: @BccHnw вот ток ток, зашел написать про synchronized  в Котлине. да, он отлично быстро работает, при этом все выполняет в разных потоках

Answer (score 0):

```
 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                (1..10000).map {
                    launch {
                        (1..10000).forEach {
                            @Synchronized
                            fun go() {
                                i++
                            }
                            go()
                        }
                    }
                }.joinAll()
                logInfo("${i}")
            }
```

Вариант с `@Synchronized` работает отлично и  быстрее `Mutex`

Comment: А зачем? Atomic класс будет быстрее и лучше. И зачем тут в функцию обёрнуто, есть функция `synchronized() { }`. К тому же synchronized блочит поток, а mutex нет

Comment: что делать в ситуации, когда это мой класс, а не AtomicInteger? mutex очень долго выполняет код

Comment: Разные ситуации - разные инструменты. Synchronized не замена Mutex, у них разный принцип работы в корутинах. И не такой Mutex и медленный, в данной задаче может и медленней Synchronized, но это не означает, что он в другой задаче будет хуже.

Comment: К тому же никто не мешает реализовать свой алгоритм синхронизации для вашего кастомного класса (Compare and Swap например, как в Atomic классах)

Comment: @IR42 а можно подробнее: в чем разница между Mutex и Synchronized? а то пока не оч понятно когда что надо использовать